# Building a python module and linking it against a MacOSX framework

Tags: c++, python, macos, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to build a Python extension on MacOSX 10.6 and to link it against several frameworks (i386 only). I made a setup.py file, using distutils and the Extension object.

I order to link against my frameworks, my **LDFLAGS** env var should look like :

```
LDFLAGS = -lc -arch i386 -framework fwk1 -framework fwk2
```

As I did not find any 'framework' keyword in the Extension module documentation, I used the **extra_link_args** keyword instead.

```
Extension('test',
define_macros = [('MAJOR_VERSION', '1'), ,('MINOR_VERSION', '0')],
include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include', 'include/', 'include/vitale'],
extra_link_args = ['-arch i386',
                   '-framework fwk1',
                   '-framework fwk2'],
sources = "testmodule.cpp",
language = 'c++' )
```

Everything is compiling and linking fine. If I remove the -framework line from the extra_link_args, my linker fails, as expected. Here is the last two lines produced by a python setup.py build :

```
/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -isysroot /
-L/opt/local/lib -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -bundle
-undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.6/testmodule.o
-o build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.6/test.so
-arch i386 -framework fwk1 -framework fwk2
```

Unfortunately, the .so that I just produced is unable to find several symbols provided by this framework. I tried to check the linked framework with otool. None of them is appearing.

```
$ otool -L test.so
test.so:
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)
```

There is the output of otool run on a test binary, made with g++ and ldd using the LDFLAGS described at the top of my post. On this example, the -framework did work.

```
$ otool -L vitaosx 
vitaosx:
    /Library/Frameworks/fwk1.framework/Versions/A/fwk1 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /Library/Frameworks/fwk2.framework/Versions/A/fwk2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)
```

May this issue be linked to the "-undefined dynamic_lookup" flag on the linking step ? I'm a little bit confused by the few lines of documentation that I'm finding on Google.

Cheers,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the undefined dynamic_lookup but all with distutils. It appends the extra_link_flags to the link flags it chooses for python building. Instead it should prepend it because the -framework listings must come before the objects that use them on the cmdline (AFAIK this is due how gcc gathers symbols for linking). A quick fix that I personally use is building with

```
    LDFLAGS="-framework Carbon" python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

or whatever frameworks you need. LDFLAGS is prepended to distutils own flags. Note that your package will not be `pip install`able. A proper fix can only come from distutils - imho they should support `frameworks` like they support `libraries`.

Alternatively, you can also add

```
import os
os.environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-framework Carbon'
```

in your setup.py. Your package should then be `pip install`able.

Answer (score 4):

Although long after the dust has settled, having the same question myself I dug around a little bit and found this:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/sysconfig.py

```
   if 'ARCHFLAGS' in os.environ:
                archflags = os.environ['ARCHFLAGS']
            else:
                archflags = '-arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64'
            _config_vars['ARCHFLAGS'] = archflags
            if archflags.strip() != '':
                _config_vars['CFLAGS'] = _config_vars['CFLAGS'] + ' ' + archflags
                _config_vars['LDFLAGS'] = _config_vars['LDFLAGS'] + ' ' + archflags
```

I'm coming at the problem from a different angle - on 10.6 distutils is trying to build C extensions and as complains because there's no PPC portion in the 10.6 SDK.

However,

```
 export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64"
 python setup.py build
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: I believe the PPC issue is only if you got the newest XCode. Ie., the one you can pay for. The one that comes with 10.6 OS disks should be fine.

Comment: I haven't tried @synthesizerpatel answer yet, but I had the ppc issue with the previous XCode. The one coming free out of MacOS X DVDs.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do and your desired outcome but perhaps this will help.  Because C extension modules are normally run within the execution context of the Python interpreter, extension modules have to be built to be compatible with the interpreter.  On OS X, Python and distutils go to some trouble to ensure that C extension modules are built with the same SDK (`-sysroot`), `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` value, and `-arch` values as the Python interpreter itself was originally built.  So, if you are using the Apple-supplied Python on 10.6, distutils will supply `-arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64`, the three archs that it was built with.  If you use a current python.org OS X installer (on 10.6, 10.5, or 10.4), it will use:

```
gcc-4.0 -arch ppc -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk
```

From the snippets you supply, I'm guessing you are using a MacPorts-installed universal Python and, by default, it is built with and uses `-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -isysroot /` for building extension modules.

Generally, to make everything work you need to ensure:

1. there is at least one `arch` in
   common among the interpreter, all C
   extension modules, and all external
   frameworks and/or shared libraries
   that they link to
2. the interpreter is executing in that (or one of those) common architecture(s).

On OS X 10.6, that last step is not as easy as it should be depending on which Python you are using.  For instance, the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 has a modification to force 32-bit execution (see Apple's `man python` for details):

```
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```

If you build your own 32-/64-bit universal Python, there are fixes in 2.6.5 to allow selection at run-time.  Unfortunately, the way MacPorts builds Python bypasses those fixes so there does not appear to be any simple way to force a MacPorts python2.6 32-/64-bit universal build on 10.6 to run in 32-bit mode.  For complicated reasons, it will always prefer 64-bit, if available, even if you use `/usr/bin/arch -i386`.

So, depending on what you are trying to do, you may be able to work around the issue (if I understand it correctly) by either:

1. rebuild your frameworks to include `-arch x86_64`
2. use the Apple-supplied Python (`/usr/bin/python`) in 32-bit mode or the python.org 2.6.5
3. reinstall the MacPorts python in 32-bit-only mode (untested!):

   ```
   sudo port selfupdate
   sudo port clean python26
   sudo port install python26 +universal universal_archs=i386
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

It seems that the linker will not reference the frameworks in the produced .so file if at least one arch is not found in the framework.

In my case, my framework includes ppc and i386 variants.

Everything is working fine with the base python distribution included in MacOSX if I manually force the -arch flags at the linking step to "i386". I may find my frameworks if I run otool on the produced .so file.

But if I use the system's defaults of -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64, the .so file is not linked to any of my frameworks.

Comment: Option 1 is unfortunately unavailable, as the frameworks are provided as it without any source. It seems impossible to get a newer version from my providers.


Option 2 is working. Thank you, I almost forgot that I had a python binary bundled with macosx...


Option 3 is, very strangely, not working. The only arch appearing on the linking step of the buildutils is i386, as expected, but the .so is not linked to any of the frameworks. I'll try to clear this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that my framework is compiled for ppc and i386 but not x86_64 :

```
$ file /Library/Frameworks/fwk1.framework/Versions/A/fwk1 
/Library/Frameworks/fwk1.framework/Versions/A/fwk1: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/fwk1.framework/Versions/A/fwk1 (for architecture ppc):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
/Library/Frameworks/fwk1.framework/Versions/A/fwk1 (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
```

I removed the -arch x86_64 flag from my linking line. My library is linked against my frameworks :

```
$ otool -L  test.so
test.so:
    /Library/Frameworks/fwk1.framework/Versions/A/fwk1 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /Library/Frameworks/fwk2.framework/Versions/A/fwk2 (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.0.1)
```

If someone know how to **force** the -arch to be used at compile and link time with Python's distutils... please share your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself.  I had to bypass distutils, because they appear to hard-code the -undefined dynamic_lookup.  Here is the Makefile I'm using to emulate distutils:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -pipe -std=c99 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -mno-fused-madd -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Werror -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -g -Os -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
LD = gcc
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-F. -bundle -Wl,-F. -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreMIDI -framework Python

project = <extension_name>
library = $(project).so
modules = <module_names>
sources = $(foreach module,$(modules),$(module).c)
objects = $(sources:.c=.o)

all: $(library)

$(library): $(objects)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(objects) -o $@

%.o: %.c Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -c -o $@

install: $(library)
    cp $(library) /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages

clean:
        rm -f $(library) $(objects) *~
```

I'm sure there is a way to get distutils to stop emitting that -undefined argument, but the above worked for me on 10.7