# How to link Mac OS framework in Cython

Tags: macos, clang, cython, cythonize

How to link Mac OS framework in Cython?

I failed with

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
ext_modules=[
    Extension("PyLexActivator",
          sources=["PyLexActivator.pyx"],
          language='c++',
          extra_objects=["libLexActivator.a"], 
          extra_link_args=['-framework CoreFoundation', 
                     '-framework SystemConfiguration'],
    )
]
setup(
  name = "PyLexActivator",
  ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules)
)
```

Error

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'PyLexActivator' extension
/usr/bin/clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/o/anaconda/include -arch x86_64 -I. -I/Users/o/anaconda/include/python3.5m -c PyLexActivator.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/PyLexActivator.o
/usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/Users/o/anaconda/lib -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/PyLexActivator.o libLexActivator.a -L/Users/o/anaconda/lib -o 
/Users/suo/Documents/guanran/face_recommend/cryptlex/PyLexActivator.cpython-35m-darwin.so -framework Foundation -framework SystemConfiguration
clang: error: unknown argument: '-framework CoreFoundation'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-framework SystemConfiguration'
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1
```

Adding the full path to the framework does not work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer from the similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584595/building-a-python-module-and-linking-it-against-a-macosx-framework).

```
import os
os.environ['LDFLAGS'] = '-framework CoreFoundation -framework SystemConfiguration'
```